# Android Studio doesn't let me create normal android project, only flutter one

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I think my question is really simple, but i couldn't find an answer. After i installed the flutter plugin i have no longer the option to create a normal(native) android project.
[image]

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Click on configure and there u can make your default changes.

Comment: in that way i will make like an app default settings. Why to do that? It must be a quicker way

Answer (score 1):

Just maximize the window :)

Your version
[image]

Maximised version.
[image]

Comment: I tried your answer but it didn't work. Then i updated Android studio and it worked i guess.
Im gonna leave it unanswered for now, if someone else had a similar problem otherwise im gonna mark it as correct!